# How to check for NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, android, exception, defensive-programming

I am getting few NoClassDefFoundError in my Android mobile app only from specific devices of Samsung and QMobile.

Will adding the below code detect the error?

```
  //Check for Class not found error for Samsung 4.2.2 devices case
  try {
      Class.forName("android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // Handle Exception by displaying an alert to user to update device firmware.
  }catch (NoClassDefFoundError e){
      // Handle Exception by displaying an alert to user to update device firmware.
  }
```

What is the best way to detect a NoClassDefFoundError proactively without ending up in app crash?

> Edit:

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) says that the method throws the below exceptions and it does not mentions anything about `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
Throws:
LinkageError - if the linkage fails
ExceptionInInitializerError - if the initialization provoked by this method fails
ClassNotFoundException - if the class cannot be located
```

I can rephrase the question like

> Will `Class.forName(String)`throw `NoClassDefFoundError` or How can I check if a class has a "Def"?

Comment: You are handling it in the catch block, it should not crash

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik I am not surrounding issue causing statement with try/catch block. I am just trying to trigger the exception proactively and check if the app continues to run, will it crash.

Comment: if it is in a particular method, why don't do a `throws NoClassDefFoundError` and handle it in the calling method.

I am just saying, there may be a better solution.

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik The exception is happening in Android Library. I can't modify the source code of the android library.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You've posted code that answers your question completely.

Comment: @EJP My question is that, whether the code I have posted will detect NoClassDefFoundError? Or is there a better way to do that.

Comment: I believe it will, there's no way `NoClassDefFoundError` could escape those catch. If it does, then your looking at the wrong source; that `NoClassDefFoundError` was thrown elsewhere.

Comment: @ridsatrio I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The try-catch is, I think, the best way to handle exceptions (which what `NoClassDefFoundError` essentially is).

But it might be wise to handle the things that caused this to happen rather than just complying with the effect; `NoClassDefFoundError` is an effect, there must be something you can do to prevent it from ever popping out.

If as you said it happened within a library then there's 2 things you can do:

- Report it to the maintainer (if you feel like this is truly their error), or
- Try to fix the cause rather than the effect (the exception). `NoClassDefFoundError` usually marks that you are missing something the library needs; be it another dependency to yet another library or perhaps something else.

Try to dig deeper into the library's documentations, you might figure something out of it.